# Flutter: How to add assets to debug build only?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, is there a way to add assets for debug builds only? Or to strip them from release builds?

The idea is to generate the play- and app-store screenshots from inside the app.
Those screenshots are composed of various images that are otherwise unused and hence shouldn't be included in the release build. Question is, can those assets somehow be removed from release builds?

As an alternative, would it be possible to load the images from the Flutter project directory while the app is running in debug mode? -or at the emulator?

Could the test folder, perhaps, be abused for it?

How would you approach that requirement?

Any advise is welcome,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use git, and create a branch for debug mode, and commit your files only in debug branch, when you need release your app, checkout to other branch like main or release, and your asset files not include in your release

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! It would for sure work, however, maintaining two branches seems a little cumbersome. Still, at least a viable workaround...

Answer (score 0):

There is no (yet?) such solution in Flutter, you can check for that opened issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64106.

The only possible solution seems to be write some script that will remove assets before you create release build.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `KDebugMode` from dart foundation like

```
if(KDebugMode){
    //your code
}
```

or

```
KDebugMode ? //your code : //do something else
```

Comment: @Mael_Toukap Thanks for sharing this. Unfortunately, `kDebugMode` isn't enough. Because, even if an asset isn't referenced in code, it's still included in the release binary.